# Класс RegistrationService для push, в чем проблема?

Tags: java, android

Создаю класс:

```
public class RegistrationService extends IntentService {
public RegistrationService() {
    super("RegistrationService");
}
String TAG = "MyLog";

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "11");
    InstanceID myID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "22");
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "33");
        String registrationToken = myID.getToken(
                getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE,
                null
        );
        Log.d("Registration Token", registrationToken);
        GcmPubSub subscription = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        subscription.subscribe(registrationToken, "/topics/my_little_topic", null);

    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

}
}
```

На моменте

```
InstanceID myID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
```

приложение падает. Где стоит поискать проблему?

Вот лог ошибки:

```
12-28 20:46:35.825 1381-1381/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@31bcfd1 that was originally bound here
                                             android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@31bcfd1 that was originally bound here
                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1336)
                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1231)
                                                 at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1478)
                                                 at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1450)
                                                 at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:636)
                                                 at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:181)
                                                 at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:224)
                                                 at com.android.email.service.EmailServiceUtils.isServiceAvailable(EmailServiceUtils.java:160)
                                                 at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccountsInternal(AccountReconciler.java:171)
                                                 at com.android.email.provider.AccountReconciler.reconcileAccounts(AccountReconciler.java:115)
                                                 at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.reconcileAndStartServices(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:305)
                                                 at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onBootCompleted(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:295)
                                                 at com.android.email.service.EmailBroadcastProcessorService.onHandleIntent(EmailBroadcastProcessorService.java:130)
                                                 at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:67)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                 at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
12-28 20:46:35.829 631-992/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 1421:com.android.messaging/u0a59 for broadcast com.android.messaging/.receiver.BootAndPackageReplacedReceiver
```

Comment: Для использования FCM вам нужен не обычный сервис. Почитайте [инструкции](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)